# Add new variable in Computed field

Tags: entities

Can I add new variable in Computed field?
The added variable will be used only in the computed field

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
Computed Field is a very powerful field module that lets you add a custom "computed
fields" to your content types.
```

> These computed fields are populated with values that you
>       define via PHP code.